# gem install mysql failure in Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, rubygems, osx-snow-leopard

I successfully installed MySql x86_64 in Snow Leopard and Ruby and Ruby Gems seems to be installed properly:

```
$ which mysql
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem
$ mysql
Your MySQL connection id is 404
Server version: 5.1.37 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [universal-darwin10.0]
$ gem -v
1.3.5
```

Unfortunatly I get an error installing mysql gem:

```
$ sudo gem update --system
...
$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Installing the Xcode that's bundled with the Snow Leopard fixed the problem.

Comment: I did, and updated the iPhone SDK to the Snow Leopard version as well.. Still get the same error, so I doubt that's the problem! :(

Comment: For me as well as a user in another post (http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/191688) that do the trick.

Comment: anyone have a suggestion for someone without the snow leopard dvd?

Answer (score 26):

I think you should try to uninstall the old mysql gem first before recompiling

```
sudo gem uninstall mysql
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Comment: it works if you have gcc or xcode installed . the above command will work well and has been working well for me till date

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was adding the UNIX Tools option (if I recalled the name accurately), which include the headers.  When I installed XCode originally, I didn't include this component because I didn't think that I would be writing UNIX code.  Little did I know...

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed MySQL 5 using MacPorts, then use the command:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/opt/local/bin/mysql_config5
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I updated to Lion.  In this case, I when to the app store and downloaded the latest Xcode.  Then I uninstalled and reinstalled the database.

The issue had to do with a broken link during the update.  Ruby likes to be in /System while Apple places ruby in /Developer.

Answer (score 0):

was stuck with same problem:
Tried most of the solution's: At the end

Edit the app/config/database.yml, change the adapter to mysql2

```
  production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: commissi_production
  username: root
  password: root
  host: localhost
```

& run on terminal

```
 gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter
```

Solved the problem.