# Can't install a ruby gem because of an error?

Tags: rubygems

Hey there, trying to install a ruby gem but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR:failed to build gem native extension

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at/System/
Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
```

I'm not exactly sure what is happening here. Is there anyone that knows what is going on and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See : [gem install mysql failure in Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366746/gem-install-mysql-failure-in-snow-leopard)